# Django - deleting users with on_delete=models.CASCADE causes problems with signals.post_delete

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

We are using Django 3.1 for our websites. We have a model, `User`, which is related to two `SiteProfile` models for two websites, and is also related to other models such as `Friend` and `UserEmailAddress`. All the relations are with `on_delete=models.CASCADE`. We also have `models.signals.post_delete` signals for models such as `Friend`, to update the number of friends a user has, which is saved in one of the `SiteProfile` models. But the problem is, when deleting a user, the signal is called and then the `SiteProfile` object is saved, and then I get an exception for `django.db.utils.IntegrityError` - violations of foreign keys. We used to have the same problem with the `UserEmailAddress` model (a user's email address), which I fixed with the following code:

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if ((self.is_staff) or (self.is_superuser)):
        warnings.warn('Can’t delete staff user.')
        return False
    else:
        with transaction.atomic():
            for user_email_address in self.email_addresses.all():
                user_email_address.delete()
            return_value = super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
        return return_value
```

But I would like to know, is there a better way to delete a user with all its related objects which have `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, but without saving the counters in `models.signals.post_delete` to the database? Can I check something in `models.signals.post_delete` to know if the user is being deleted and then don't save the counters? Since I don't want to specifically delete any related object in the `def delete` method - there are at least 5 such models not including the two `SiteProfile` models.

Comment: Why even save the number of friends a user has? You can simply get that by making a query, try replacing that field with a property which makes a query using the orm to get the value and now you don't need your signal anymore!

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Performance. It takes about 50% less time to read a field from the model than to query the database for the number of friends, especially for thousands of users.